# Local SSL certificate returning errors "result too small", "problems getting password"

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp

I'm trying to install an SSL certificate on XAMPP, Windows 10 but no matter what I do I get this error:

```
22632:error:28069065:lib(40):UI_set_result:result too small:.\crypto\ui\ui_lib.c:830:You must type in 4 to 511 characters
22632:error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting password:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:116:
22632:error:0907E06F:PEM routines:DO_PK8PKEY:read key:.\crypto\pem\pem_pk8.c:130:
unable to load Private Key
18224:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
server.csr: No such file or directory
Could Not Find c:\xampp\apache\server.csr
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.

-----
Das Zertifikat wurde erstellt.
The certificate was provided.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

makecert.bat:

```
@echo off
set OPENSSL_CONF=./conf/openssl.cnf

if not exist .\conf\ssl.crt mkdir .\conf\ssl.crt
if not exist .\conf\ssl.key mkdir .\conf\ssl.key

bin\openssl req -new -out server.csr
bin\openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out server.key
bin\openssl x509 -in server.csr -out server.crt -req -signkey server.key -days 365

set OPENSSL_CONF=
del .rnd
del privkey.pem
del server.csr

move /y server.crt .\conf\ssl.crt
move /y server.key .\conf\ssl.key

pause
```

It looks like `server.crt`, `server.csr`, and `server.key` were created and they sit in the conf/sll... as stated in makecert.bat , I have also tried other passwords with no success.

Setting `set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf` didn't help either, nor did changing `openssl.cnf` to `openssl.cfg` (like some people suggest on other related SO questions).

I'm spamming google with this question for hours and no Stack Overflow answers seemed to help either.

**EDIT:** Adding an image to show that this issue is happening even with a completely new `pem` file. (the `pem` file name was changed to `privkey77.pem` by me for testing purposes, I get the same error obviously).

[image]png

**EDIT #2:** Even creating a new key with password with `openssl genrsa -des3 -out mykey.pem 2048` returns: `27492:error:28069065:lib(40):UI_set_result:result too small:.\crypto\ui\ui_lib.c:830:You must type in 4 to 1023 characters`.

So I basically cannot create `pem` files with passwords for some reason.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: `privkey.pem` seems to hold a private key protected by a password and you are no entering the correct one, which makes everything later fail.

Comment: The problem is... I don't have a privkey.pem anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I've found it. I don't remember setting a different pass but is there a way to reset it?

Comment: `bin\openssl rsa -in privkey.pem` ... it clearly reads (`-in`) the file `privkey.pem`... so without it you will never be able to create certificates. Or you need to create a new one (but that depends on your constraints, a change of private key can be a problem)

Comment: You can not change the password ( or remove it which is the same as a change), if you do not know the current one... The only other options is to start from scratch with a new private key. See for example https://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#how-do-i-generate-an-rsa-key to see how to create a new one. As for the old one also try just enter when asked for a password, maybe it was empty.

Comment: I knew that it wasn't that because today was the first time setting up SSL. I've created a new `pem` and still get the same error with `makecert.bat`, any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172118/discussion-between-ricardo-and-patrick-mevzek).

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to avoid this error by passing the `-nodes` arg to the line that triggers the error, as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/407908/why-openssl-insist-on-requiring-a-passphrase-on-genrsa-command#comment1486512_407936).

My `makecert.bat` file, in line 7, looks like this:

`bin\openssl req -new -out server.csr -nodes`

This parameter disables the authentication completely. I don't know if this had any side effects in the certificate, since I haven't managed to make it work and I don't know why. (Maybe is because of this, or maybe is something else)

Comment: I've reinstalled XAMPP and was paying special attention to the password when typing it in. 
Pay attention that CMD won't indicate that you are writing your password, and it may look that you are not actually writing anything (especially if you're new to this), you should write it anyway instead of trying to disable authentication.
Hope this helps.